# How to calculate `percent_rank` on past time values in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to calculate the `percent_rank` of a column `x`, but the rank should be relative to *past* values only - as determined by a time stamp variable `t`.

It seems `F.percent_rank()` accepts no arguments and to get ranks independent of time you would use `percent_rank().over(Window.orderBy("x"))`?!

Is there any way to get ranks based on the population of values which have a *smaller* timestamp?

The expected results is something like

```
t     x     perc_rank_win
0     1     0.0
1     3     1.0           # since 3 is largest from [1, 3]
2     5     1.0           # since 5 is largest from [1, 3, 5]
3     4     0.66          # since values are [1, 3, 4!, 5]
4     2     0.25          # since [1, 2!, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another work around I tried using collect_set over window partition,

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([(0,1),(1,3),(2,5),(3,4),(4,2)],['t','x'])
df.show()
+---+---+
|  t|  x|
+---+---+
|  0|  1|
|  1|  3|
|  2|  5|
|  3|  4|
|  4|  2|
+---+---+
w = Window.orderBy('t')
df = df.withColumn('somecol',F.collect_set('x').over(w))
df.show()
+---+---+---------------+
|  t|  x|        somecol|
+---+---+---------------+
|  0|  1|            [1]|
|  1|  3|         [1, 3]|
|  2|  5|      [1, 5, 3]|
|  3|  4|   [1, 5, 3, 4]|
|  4|  2|[1, 5, 2, 3, 4]|
+---+---+---------------+
def pct_rank(s,v):
    x=sorted(s)
    if len(x) == 1:
        return float(0)
    else:
        pc = float(1)/(len(x)-1)
        idx = x.index(v)
        return float("{0:.2f}".format(idx*pc))

pct_udf = F.udf(pct_rank)
df.select("t","x",pct_udf(df['somecol'],df['x']).alias('pct_rank')).show()
+---+---+--------+
|  t|  x|pct_rank|
+---+---+--------+
|  0|  1|     0.0|
|  1|  3|     1.0|
|  2|  5|     1.0|
|  3|  4|    0.67|
|  4|  2|    0.25|
+---+---+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a rolling `percent_rank()`, you would have to be able to use window frame definition for ranking funtions which you simply can't. ( something like this `w = Window.orderBy('t', 'x').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)`)

I found a way around it but it involves a cartesian join which is very costly:

First let's create the example dataframe:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hc = HiveContext(sc)
df = hc.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(zip(range(5), [1,3,5,4,2])), ['t', 'x'])
```

Cartesian join:

```
df2 = df.groupBy(df.x.alias('x2')).agg(psf.min("t").alias("t2"))
df_cross = df.join(df2).filter("t2 <= t").withColumn("isSup", (df.x > df2.x2).cast("int"))

    +---+---+---+---+-----+
    |  t|  x| t2| x2|isSup|
    +---+---+---+---+-----+
    |  1|  3|  0|  1|    1|
    |  2|  5|  0|  1|    1|
    |  2|  5|  1|  3|    1|
    |  3|  4|  0|  1|    1|
    |  3|  4|  1|  3|    1|
    |  3|  4|  2|  5|    0|
    |  4|  2|  0|  1|    1|
    |  4|  2|  1|  3|    0|
    |  4|  2|  2|  5|    0|
    |  4|  2|  3|  4|    0|
    +---+---+---+---+-----+
```

Finally we group by 't', 'x':

```
df_fin = df_cross.groupBy("t", "x").agg(
    psf.count("*").alias("count"), 
    psf.sum("isSup").alias("rank")
).withColumn('pct_rank_win', psf.col("rank")/psf.greatest(psf.col('count') - 1, psf.lit(1)))

    +---+---+-----+----+------------------+
    |  t|  x|count|rank|      pct_rank_win|
    +---+---+-----+----+------------------+
    |  0|  1|    1|   0|               0.0|
    |  1|  3|    2|   1|               1.0|
    |  2|  5|    3|   2|               1.0|
    |  3|  4|    4|   2|0.6666666666666666|
    |  4|  2|    5|   1|              0.25|
    +---+---+-----+----+------------------+
```

The `groupBy('x')` in `df2` definition is to ensure a dense ranking (same values will have the same rank) as shown with the following example:

```
df = hc.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(zip(range(6), [1,3,3,5,4,2])), ['t', 'x'])

    +---+---+-----+----+------------------+
    |  t|  x|count|rank|      pct_rank_win|
    +---+---+-----+----+------------------+
    |  0|  1|    1|   0|               0.0|
    |  1|  3|    2|   1|               1.0|
    |  2|  3|    2|   1|               1.0|
    |  3|  5|    3|   2|               1.0|
    |  4|  4|    4|   2|0.6666666666666666|
    |  5|  2|    5|   1|              0.25|
    +---+---+-----+----+------------------+
```